# Add constraints to <include> inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Please take a look at my xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not able to add constraint to the `<include>`. The `app` namespace doesn't work (it works for the `RelativeLayout`) and auto fill doesn't show the constraint attributes. I want the included layout's height to be the remaining space in the `ConstraintLayout`, but how do I do it without constraints! Please help.

Comment: What does "The app namespace doesn't work" mean? Do you mean it doesn't compile? Then what error message is given? Do you mean you get the wrong result? What result do you get?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <include
         layout="@layout/page"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: size is important. Worked after the '<include' was given width and height.

Comment: In some cases specifying the size of <include/> make your include meaningless. Good example - simple dividers.

Answer (score 8):

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_no_friends_avalable"
                 android:id="@+id/inc_no_friend"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_main"
        />
```

When adding constraints in `<include>` tag we must use `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` both attributes.

Comment: For the people that have styles defining margins and paddings inside their included xml, because the <include> tag is overriding everything by defining height and width, the parameters also need to be brought to the front. (At least this is what happened to my divider)

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_info"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<include
    layout="@layout/page"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```